# Is it valid to apply large scale statistics to a single case?

Tags: probability, forecasting, frequency, mathematical-statistics

I have a small black box that displays a 0 or a 1 every time I press its button.

I can tell you, truthfully, that over the past 20,000,000,000 times it has been pressed, 19,999,999,990 times it has shown a 1.

I ask you to make a prediction of what number will appear when I press the button next.

For the sake of simplicity, I won't attach any form of consequences to the results. You make a guess, and you are either right or wrong.

How do you make your choice, and in what way do you find that choice to be valid?

---

Here's some other constraints that you can feel free to apply or discard if you think the result would be interesting:

```
1. The temporal distribution of the recorded results is unknown.
2. The display is blank until the button is pressed, and the digit will appear for a short amount of time afterwards. It is blank when you see it. 
3. The button being pressed causes the display of the digit.
```

Comment: I had a discussion that led me to Propensity Probability and a problem like this, and thought I would see if there were any other rational answers for this problem.

Comment: Any additional info available about when the zeros occurred in the sequence of 20 billion presses, or whether either number is displayed by default (i.e., does the button display something that doesn't appear otherwise, or does it change the display only sometimes), or whether the relationship between the button and the display is causal (i.e., does the button actually affect the display)?

Comment: Feel free to explore any of those possibilities and how they would affect your decision, but I can add some specifics to the problem if that would help. I would assume a random temporal distribution. The display is blank until the button is pressed, and the digit will appear for a short amount of time afterwards. It is blank when you see it. The button being pressed causes the display. But again, feel free to inform me on how a different constraint would change the problem significantly and use that as rationale.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First I would like to say that I'm not sure if I fully understand what you ask in your actual question. The whole concept of statistics (or more rigorously inference theory) is to draw conclusions from the given data, so yes it is possible to use statistics to make predictions about a single case as long as you have any data to base you prediction on. You would not need statistics to predict the outcome if you know all the variables and relations in the the process exactly.

In your example you are asking for a prediction of the next outcome in some unknown random process. We have no knowledge of the dependence between the trials you describe. What we do know is that we have a dichotomous outcome ($0$ or $1$) with an unknown probability $p$.

Essentially what we are looking for is the conditional expectation of the next state given all previous values. 
$$
  E[X_{i+1}|X_i, X_{i-1}, \ldots, X_0]
$$

Here we need to make an assumption on the dependence between trials in order to continue. Lets investigate both possible assumptions.

### 1. Independent trials

Assuming the trials are independent, i.e the expected outcome is independent of previous outcomes. If this is the case you describe something which is known as a [Bernoulli trial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial). The best estimator of the probability of success (to get $1$) is the sample mean. 
$$
 \hat p = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=0}^N x_i,
$$
where $x_i$ are each of our previously recorded outcomes. Each outcome is however not given in the problem but instead only the count of events displaying $1$ (lets call this sum $T$). Luckily $T$ is a sufficient statistic for the probability parameter $p$ of the Bernoulli distribution. By sufficient statistic we mean a summary statistic containing all information about the sought parameter.
$$
 \hat p = \frac{1}{N}T = \frac{19999999990}{20000000000} \approx 1.
$$
This gives us a probability very close to 1 of getting a $1$ in a trial. The expectation of the next trial is thus
$$
 E[X_{i+1}] = p \approx 1
$$
And our best estimate of the next trial is $1$ with a very high probability.

### 2. Conditional trials

Here we assume the expected outcome is dependent on previous outcomes. This seems very reasonable, since as the process is unknown we cannot rule out that we have a dependence on previous values. However, dependence is something we cannot really address as we have only been given a summary statistic which is not sufficient for models making use of this dependence. (At least I do not know of any such model)

Say for example that the process is a Markov process with a large probability of staying in the same state. In this case our prediction in the independent model might be very wrong if the last observation was $0$. However, as the summary statistic ($T$) given in the problem statement is not sufficient for the parameters in this model.

### Conclusion

This leaves us with only one option. In order to make a prediction given the data at hand we have to assume independence. If we were to use a more complex model without the support of data we would have to start guessing.

The best prediction given the data is therefore $1$.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Sorry if I sound pedantic, but can you give a citation or explanation on why it's reasonable to expect that the i+1 trial will be 1? My understanding is that probability only describes a relative frequency over time (frequentism) and as such using a calculated probability to predict the result of a single trial is not valid. At least, this is the point of contention for me.

Comment: No worries, but I thought I did. I think what you are after is some deeper discussion on the meaning of probability. Probability absolutely makes sense in one trial. Take the example of throwing a fair die. Each throw you will have a 1/6 chance of getting 1 (or whatever single outcome you want) regardless if the die is hidden or not. This is not based on any frequenzy of the outcomes but the structure of the problem. The probability simply states how big your chance is of getting the desired outcome. If you cannot see this probability directly you can estimate it using previous observations.

Comment: That is what I am after I believe. I'm finding more and more that it's not a commonly touched subject. Thanks for your help though.